# Zeros of Hilbert series of affine toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, toric-varieties

Consider a convex rational polyhedral cone $C\subset\mathbb R^m$ with vertex at the origin. Let $X$ be the corresponding affine toric variety, i.e. $\mathbb C[X]=\mathbb C[\mathbb Z^m\cap C^\circ]$. Next consider the *multivariate Hilbert series* of $X$ $$S=\sum_{a\in\mathbb Z^m\cap C^\circ} x_1^{a_1}\ldots x_m^{a_m}.$$

Each summand in this series can be viewed as a function from $\mathbb C[X]$ which lets us speak of convergence in points of $X$. In fact, one may show that $S$ converges absolutely within a (metrically) open subset of $X$ to a rational function $\sigma\in\mathbb C(X)$. My question is: what is known about the geometric properties of $\sigma$ and, in particular, about its set of zeros?

Comment: Here $C^{\circ}$ must be the dual cone (not the interior)?

Comment: @JohnMachacek Yep, the polar dual body.

Comment: Great. I just wanted to clarify because I usually see $C^{\wedge}$ for the dual. Do you have a reference for this multivariate Hilbert series? I don't recall seeing it in standard references (i.e. Fulton's book), but I may have missed it.

Comment: @JohnMachacek Well, part of the problem is that I haven't really seen this object discussed much in the context of toric geometry. I have, however, found this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703672. There this notion is introduced on page 4 as $\mathrm{Hilb}(\sigma)$ and it being a rational function on the torus is mentioned on the next page.

Comment: @JohnMachacek If you have any questions concerning the definitions I'll be glad to answer.